# How to make FF and IE act the same when pressing the back button with hash marks#

Tags: jquery, firefox, accordion

Im using a jquery accordian that uses hash marks to differentiate between open accordion tabs.

demo page

http://sandbox.unwrongest.com/jquery.accordion/

When clicking through a few tabs then using the back button, Firefox only displays hash values changing.

In IE the hash values don't change with the back button and goes directly to the previous page.

I would like Firefox to act the same as IE... not something I say very often.

Thanks to anyone with some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jquery history plugin which enables back buttons with AJAX calls

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

I have used it in one of our major e-commerce B2B application and is really very good.